# how classifieds site makes all the posted ad visible to search engines?

Tags: html, seo

I want to create a classifieds site in which the ads posted by users are saved in a database. But i want all of the posted ads to be visible in search engines instead of just being displayed on my website. So how do I optimize all data of my database using SEO.

Comment: this is the better site for basic SEO questions http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines see **web pages**. Exactly like your visitors. If an ad is visible on your web page, this page has a URL and this URL is linked to from somewhere, search engines will find it. It doesn't matter whether this web page is static, generated dynamically from database content or written by trained monkeys on the fly, it's all the same if it's a web page.

Comment: sir i meant that if i post a free classified add in any free classified website it becomes available in google search in some while .the add gets stored in a database and is not displayed on any web page unless the query is called.so how the content which is stored in database(not in a website)is visible to google??

Comment: @Robin A classified, by definition, must be visible *somewhere* on an index page even if not explicitly searched for, otherwise it's pointless. There's the possibility that the page in question regularly submits a sitemap to Google, but I doubt that. Do you have any specific example of a classified page you're mystified by?

Comment: yes definitely.. www.quikr.com makes all its adds visible to search engine in some minutes..u can take example of stackoverflow too.while we r discussing over this topic on this website this question can be tracked from google if someone search related to this topic.how to do it??

Comment: @Robin **There is no secret sauce.** Quikr very publicly lists all its ads in index pages, where they are found by Google. Same for Stackoverflow. Google is simply crawling these sites very aggressively. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127935/how-to-end-up-in-google-search-results-within-minutes

Comment: finally i have found a solution of using asp.net code to create customised meta tags and title to provide a better seo for my page.i am implementing that method .well thanks a lot mentors for ur valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

every classified must be a landingpage, ever landingpage gets communicated to google (i.e.: with a sitemap.xml http://sitemaps.org/)